# $this PHP returns null

Tags: php

Just wondering why the get method returns Null

```
class Test
{
 
    protected $title;

    public function setTitle($ttl)
    {    
        
        $this->title = $ttl;
    }

    public function getTitle()
    {
        var_dump($this->title);  return Null ??? 
        return (string) $this->title;

    }
```

Calling the methods

in Controller 1

```
$test = new Test();
$test->setTitle('ttl');
```

get Method in Controller 2

```
$test->getTitle();  return Null
```

Comment: I am amazed it returns anything at all. Can you make your code valid?

Comment: You would need to call `setTitle` before `getTitle` for it to be defined.  If you don't want `null` you would need `protected $title = '';` or something

Comment: Lack of context is preventing us from seeing precisely what is going on. Please a) make the code compilable, and b) show you're instantiating and then using the class. As AbraCadaver says, if you've never previously set the title, then clearly you'd never be able to get it either.

Comment: of course I'm calling the 2 functions in another controller file

Comment: Show us the calling code too, pls.

Comment: I only see you setting a title in one controller, and getting a title in another controller. Are both those controllers happening in the SAME page run? Or different times? Your code example is really unclear.

Comment: Objects you instantiate (create by using 'new') in one controller are only usable within that controller. They don't exist in other controllers. Only variables at the global scope are visible everywhere.

Comment: Try to provide a use case of what you are trying to do in your app, not how you are trying to do it. It seems that your mind went deep into looking at the problem from a wrong perspective.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `getTitle();` in another controller, then you need to export your object from the first controller. Because that's how OOP works. 
If you create in a file something like this:

```
$title= new Title();
$title->setTitle('tlt');
```

And you go in another file(controller) and write this:

```
$title = new Title();
$title->getTitle('tlt');
```

You'll get `NULL`. This is because the `$title` from the first Controller isn't the same object with the `$title` from the second controller.

Try to use a function to export your object: try this in the first controller

```
function exports(){
$title= new Title();
$title->setTitle('tlt');
return $title
}
```

And this in the second:

```
$title = exports();
$title->getTitle();
```

Comment: Thanks, but why If I change the $title property to static with using self::$title in methods it retrieve the data normally

Comment: @A0twa try to read about "static" variables and methods. That's what they do, they keep the information even after the code is run. In computer programming, a static variable is a variable that has been allocated "statically", meaning that its lifetime (or "extent") is the entire run of the program (wiki)